# Color rows of a dataframe containing True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

*I would like to color all the rows of the dataframe that have the value 'True' in the 'Alert' column. I tried everything but nothing worked. *

```
Ch_Output = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
controllo = [False, False, True, False,True, False]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Ch_Output, controllo)), columns =['Canali', 'Alert'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


Ch_Output = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
controllo = [False, False, True, False,True, False]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Ch_Output, controllo)), columns =['Canali', 'Alert'])



def highlight_True(s):
    is_mos = df['Alert'] == True
    return ['color: green' if v else 'color: red' for v in is_mos]

s = df.style.apply(highlight_True)
s
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).:

```
styles = df['Alert'].map({True: 'color: green', False: 'color: red'})

df.style.apply(lambda _: styles)
```

Or with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

styles = np.where(df['Alert'], 'color: green', 'color: red')

df.style.apply(lambda _: styles)
```

*Note: Be sure to compute the `styles` once and reuse the same values instead of recalculating the same values for each column.

Both Produce:

[image: styled table]